# WPML custom post type - not translated

Tags: plugin-wpml

I just installed a WPML, but my custom post types is showing just in default language, if I am switching to other languages, it will show the same posts as default language, but in wordpress panel they are translated.

Part of my code in function.php

```
$args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','taxonomy')
```

And to get those post types I am using :

```
query_posts('post_type=objekts');
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which versions of WPML and WordPress are you using? I'm sure that you noticed that the old versions of WPML from wp.org only run on old WordPress versions (up to 3.0.5).

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate WPML support for your custom post type?

- WPML > Translation Options

You should see a list of custom post types and you can  set them to allow translation.

Comment: Sure. Already did that (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8228019/custom.PNG), it just isnt reacting when I am switching languages in front-end, in back-end panel i assume everything is fine. Maybe I need to change some code? Or maybe I have to buy the newest version of plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have 'has_archive' => true in your post-type declaration.

Comment: Why would this be a solution?